# how to create a result of double number with zero?

Tags: java, android, double

I know how much what i'm asking about so easy, but i don't know how to search about my problem here because my question is so weird !!
I do something like calculator using double, float function,

and this is my code :

```
float rn7mabv,resultbsa; 
double result; 
result=rn7mabv *resultbsa/1.73;
DecimalFormat fresult = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
String finaresult = fresult.format(result);
rresult.setText(String.valueOf(finaresult));
```

but the result appear like this :

> .912

and i want to be appear like this:

> 0.912

keep in your mind sometimes there is numbers before the decimal and sometimes no:

> 1.912

So, please,,, How to do that

Comment: Why not `rresult.setText(finaresult);` but `rresult.setText(String.valueOf(finaresult));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the wrong pattern to `DecimalFormat`. Change "#.000" to "0.000" can solve your problem.

The leading zeroes are not shown if you use "#". [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is the document of `DecimalFormat`, please refer to the part of **Special Pattern Characters**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different `DecimalFormat`? Like `new DecimalFormat("0.000");` for example? You can read more about that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Comment: this is more looks like a question not answer